# Not work WHERE IN sql INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want WHERE data select with $find, but it(WHERE) not work in following query and my output is `There is not`, how fix it?

```
$find="hello";
$query = $this->db->query('
SELECT tour_foreign.name, 
       tour_foreign_residence.name_re, 
       tour_foreign_airline.name_airline, 
       tour_foreign.service, 
       tour_foreign.date_go, 
       tour_foreign.date_back, 
       tour_foreign.term 
FROM   tour_foreign 
       INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
         ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation ) 
       INNER JOIN tour_foreign_airline 
         ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_airline.relation ) 
WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
        OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%' . $find . '%"


');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $val) {
        echo $val->name . '<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'There is not';
}
```

Comment: `JOIN` should have just 1 `ON`, :   `JOIN ... ON (... AND ... )`. You have 2 : `JOIN... ON ... AND ON ...`. Is it just a misprint ? Also, you have a comma before `WHERE` which is also syntax error.

Comment: On first glance your SQL statement looks ok. My suggestion: echo the SQL statement instead of `there is not` to see if there are other issues involved (p.e. no data in the database etc.).

Comment: Bingo. a1ex07 has the problem: You've got a syntax error in your join clause, causing the entire query to fail.

Comment: @a1ex07 - i change code please see my post again.

Comment: JOIN sets the rules for combining the tables in the WHERE - filter the result.

Comment: @Nicole Spears: Can you post some data in your tables and expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma before the `WHERE` (after tour_foreign_airline.relation).

**Edit:** I see you fixed it now, but the `JOIN` still looks wrong.  Try this:

```
INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence
ON (tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation)
INNER JOIN tour_foreign_airline
ON (tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_airline.relation)
```

Comment: I change code(please see my post), but still there is output `There is not`. i done this : `echo $query->num_rows();` this echo output is `0` why??? Do it is cause that not identical names `id` with `relation`?

Comment: @NicoleSpears Assuming that `$this->db` is a wrapper around MySQLi, try this after the query: `echo $this->db->error;`

Comment: I put `echo $this->db->error;` but get this error for it `Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_driver::$error`

Comment: @NicoleSpears I see, try this one instead: `echo $this->db->_error_message();`